# How do I call a method on my WPF Page from the Modal Window?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I call a method of the **WPF Page** from the **Modal Window**?

When I use the below code, I get an error on the line *window.Owner = this;*

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyApplication1.Pages.Page1' to
>   'System.Windows.Window'

My Code:

```
// Code in main window
ModalWindow window = new ModalWindow();
window.Owner = this; 
window.ShowDialog()

//Code on the modal window
var myObject = this.Owner as MainWindow;
myObject.MyMethod(); // Call your method here.
```

Comment: If you are using MVVM Light, you can use messages for things like this as well. The main window registers for a message, and when received, kicks off a process;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to raise an event from the modal window, this way it isn't tightly coupled and you could reuse the modalwindow for other purposes.

For example a MainWindow which shows a modal dialog.

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    public void ShowMyDialog()
    {
        // create the modal dialog
        ModalWindow window = new ModalWindow();
        // bind the event
        window.OnCallMyMethod += MyMethod;
        // show dialog
        window.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void MyMehod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // insert code here that should be triggered by the dialog.
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ModalWindow : Window
{
    // declaration of event
    public event EventHandler OnCallMyMethod;

    // for example: when a button is clicked, it should trigger the event.
    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // raise the event.
        OnCallMyMethod?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

This way you modal dialog does not depends on the MainWindow. Perhaps you should change the definitions for your needs.

A thing to keep in mind is, In case of a parent (mainWindow) and a child (modalWindow) exists. The parent knows everything what methods/event the child has, but the child should not know anything who/what his parent is. So his communication back to the parent should be done via his events.

Note: The OnCallMyMethod is not a good description of what it does or should do.